# How write data by spark and get aggregation ame time?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say I have read a dataset by Spark. Next, I want to save it in parquet format and get a `max(column)` value. Both actions require dataset to read: 1) to calculate max value 2) to write it in another format.

Can Spark be setup to read dataset once and calculate max value **during** write operation?

Answer (score 0):

No,

first you calculate the max then you write it.

calculte max and write it is different stage/task ..

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually Spark tries parallelise a SINGLE operation (JOB) and then Move to next operation and parallelise it.

Ideally spark does not run 2 independent/disjoint operations in 2 different threads.

Basically Spark is for `distributed computing` and what you are looking for essentially comes under the `MULTITHREADING` category .

---

Said that, Technically you can achieve this using threadpool or futures ([Sample Example](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/how-to-use-threads-in-spark-job-to-achieve-parallel-read-and-writes/)) , But overall it will take the same amount of time as resource would be distributed.